# Supermarket 'wonky apples'

Tags: apples

My local Aldi supermarket in UK sells 'wonky apples' (from Poland).

I understand that they might be misshapen or otherwise imperfect, but what variety of apple are they?

I don't care what they look like but I do want to eat a variety that I like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can’t give you an authoritative answer for how the UK branch handles it, but in Germany Aldi Süd (which is the branch that also covers the UK) lists the specific variety on the part of the package that gets printed or labeled individually per batch. It’s not very prominent, but it’s there. Note that the variety that goes into these bags can vary, so if you have preferences, you need to check before each purchase.

Comment: Thank you I will take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: It's quite likely that they do this - they certainly do for plenty of other fruit where the variety isn't prominent. It's a while since I've been in Aldi, so my example is from Lidl - "British Apples" have the variety in small black print in a white box. They're often not well known varieties

Comment: These ones are Gala apples. The small print uses special ink, that is only visible when you've read every other word three times over.